# How to get child component values while on save LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-events

I have this child component

```
<c-picklistutility class="meettype" value={typevalue} object-name="TestObj__c" field-name="TestF__c"
       onselected={handleChange}></c-picklistutility>
```

On load `typevalue` is not going to have any value. Its getting assigned in the child component. Basically i am checking if there is any value in `typevalue` assign it as default one in picklist else if  any value is passed assign that one as default one.

The issue i am facing is i am unable to get the default selected value when i am trying to save. On save i am trying  `this.template.querySelector('.meettype').value;`, but i am not getting anything.

Child JS

```
  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.value) {
      this.template.querySelector('select').value = this.value;
    } else
      if (this.options) {
        this.template.querySelector('select').value = this.options[0].value
      }
  }
```

HTML (child)

```
       <select class="slectval slds-select" name={index} onchange={selectionChangeHandler}
            disabled={isPicklistDisabled} required={isAttributeRequired}>
            <template for:each={options} for:item="option">
                <option key={option.label} class="uiInputSelectOption" value={option.value}>
                    {option.value}
                </option>
            </template>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

This because the `value` attribute is probably decorated with an `api` decorator.

When you do this, `value` becomes read-only within this component.

You need a public `@api value` var + a private `_value` var and a getter/setter.

Eg:

```
@api
set value(val) {
  this._value = val;
}
get value() {
  return this._value;
}
```

Then, you need to make your `selectionChangeHandler` write to _value, not value.

Don't forget to define a `_value` var.

Comment: +1 though it's kind of unusual to use `value_` as opposed to `_value` or even `$value`.

Comment: changed to `_value` but never `$value` because... ugh